# Jest Mocking: TypeError: this.A.getDynamoEntry is not a function

Tags: node.js, jestjs, typeerror

I have a class A that is using another class(B)'s method. I am trying to write test for the class B and mocking the methods of the class A. But even if I mock, I am getting TypeError: this.A.getDynamoEntry is not a function. I have followed exactly the same steps given by the docs.

test.js file:

```
import A from '../../src/dao/A'
import  B from '../../src/dao/B'


jest.mock('../../src/dao/A', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      getDynamoEntry: jest.fn(()=> Promise.resolve(2)),
      putDynamoEntry: jest.fn(),
      updateDynamoEntry: jest.fn(),
      deleteDynamoEntry: jest.fn()


    };
  });
});
beforeAll(() => {
  initConfig()
  
})

describe('Test', () => {
  let entity

  beforeEach(() => {
    entity = new B()
  })

  it('getFraudLogosByOwnerId', async () => {
    const resp = await entity.getFraudLogosByOwnerId(913035121393899)
    expect(resp).toBe(2)

  })
})
```

class A:

```
class A {
  constructor(tableName, dynamoClient) {
    this.dynamoClient = dynamoClient
    this.tableName = tableName
  }
  async getDynamoEntry(query) {
    try {
      return await this.dynamoClient.query(query).promise()
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
  async putDynamoEntry(imageEntity) {
    try {
      return await this.dynamoClient.put({ TableName: this.tableName, Item: imageEntity }).promise()
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
  async updateDynamoEntry(params) {
    try {
      return await this.dynamoClient.update(params).promise()
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
  async deleteDynamoEntry(criteria) {
    try {
      return await this.dynamoClient.delete(criteria).promise()
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
}
module.exports = A
```

Class B:

```
const dynamoQueryHelper = require('./DynamoQueryHelper')
const A = require('./A')
class B {
  constructor() {
    this.A = new A("table1", "client1")
  }

  async getFraudLogosByOwnerId(ownerId) {
    const query = dynamoQueryHelper.getQuery("123", "table1")
    try {
      return await this.A.getDynamoEntry(query)
    } catch (error) {
      IPSLogger.logError(
        error,
        LogConstants.FRAUD_DATA_ACCESS_DAO,
        LogConstants.GET_FRAUD_LOGO,
        ownerId,
        LogConstants.LOG_GET_FRAUD_IMAGE_BY_OWNER_ID.replace(LogConstants.PLACEHOLDER, ownerId)
      )
      throw error
    }
  }
}

module.exports = B
```

I tried the steps given in https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks but to no avail